# Proof explain algebraic integer in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have question about proof in book Elements of Number Theory (Stillwell). Idea is to prove what number can be algebraic integer in  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. 
My question is:
why is this $2b$ in proof (red color in image)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Why is this $2b$ in the proof"? Because $(2b)^2=4b^2$. Thus we have 
$$a^2-db^2=\frac{1}{4}\left((2a)^2-d(2b)^2\right).$$ 
Hence $(2a)^2-d(2b)^2$ is divisible by $4$, i.e., $(2a)^2-d(2b)^2\equiv 0\bmod 4$.